# How to pre-populate database on a Phoenix application start-up?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have this schema:

```
schema "editables" do
    field :title, :string 
    field :content, :binary
   timestamps
end
```

I would like that on application start-up a few rows were automatically created and populated, say I want to create 6 entries with the `:title` field containing: page1, page2,...
I should I do it?

Comment: You want to insert these every time the application starts? This smells a bit.

Comment: Yes. As soon as the application starts. In production this shouldn't be a problem. My goal is to have this for HTML edition by users. It would be nice to have several predefined fields that are editable by users using HTML `content editable` but were hardcoded as HTML. Is there anything strange with this?

Comment: Can't you just set an initial value in the form, when the `editable` is created?

Comment: No, because my goal is not to use forms (ajax instead) so that users can edit hardcoded HTML (I need to have Ids/other key already set up so hat they can edit those fields).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My suggestion: create an script file that will populate the database. Let's call it `priv/repo/seeds.exs`:

```
alias MyApp.Repo
Repo.insert! %MyApp.Data{...}
Repo.insert! %MyApp.Data{...}
```

In development you can run it as

```
mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs
```

or when you need in production:

```
MIX_ENV=prod mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs
```

I can't see any reason for you to do this every time the app starts. Imagine every command you run in development, test or production now needs to pay the penalty of creating data in the database. It is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, so your suggestion is to make a script that I can run using Mix whenever i want to populate the database instead of putting code in the project in a lib (or other .ex) file, for example. Did I get it wright?

Comment: OK, I think I got it. I was biased because coming from Meteor I used to do it inside a function `Meteor.startup` that runs code when a client or a server starts...Thank you for finding time to answer me.

Comment: A big UAU for you, Chris and the rest of the team. I'm amazed because the solution was already in place in the project files (I never looked into it before...) and the documentation is superb, linking to definitions allowing newcomers to understand it all! Deep appreciation.

Comment: When using Exrm for production releases, a separate solution is required that doesn't depend on Mix. One solution is described here: https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues/67#issuecomment-183457937